# Is it possible for the game to be unwinnable?

Tags: dex

Because it seems I need credits for some plot-important things, like buying Iain's Death footage from Speedy for 300 credits.

If I tried to empty out all my pockets by repeatedly buying and selling all my stuff, and did Georji's mission to sabotage all the vending machines... Since it looks like they can only be hacked once for credits...

Where would I get money from? Or are all credit checks optional? Like how I can Convince Ellie or just threaten her, instead of using the footage?